# Issue while converting file in UNIX

Tags: excel, csv, unix, converters

My requirement is to convert pipe separated file into normal excel. So I used the below tr command in UNIX to perform this operation. `tr '|' ',' < filename.csv > filename_Final.csv` when I executed the above command it brings the negative sign of the field to field end. So I tried to bring the negative sign to front of the field I dint find correct matching UNIX script. If anyone come across a similar instance, kindly help. Input: Pipe file

```
1|abc|-123
2|def|456
3|ijk|789
```

After tr execution
`tr '|' ',' < filename.csv > filename_Final.csv`
Output: Pipe file is bifurcated into normal columns. After execution of tr command pipe delimited text was separated into excel but it brings negative sign to back of the text. 
I need negative sign to be in front of the text and to perform same convertion of pipe delimited file into excel.

```
1   abc 123-
2   def 456
3   ijk 789
```

My requirement is to convert the pipe delimited text to excel and with negative sign in front of the text.
Input

```
1|abc|-123
2|def|456
3|ijk|789
```

Expected output

```
1       abc     -123
2       def     456
3       ijk     789
```

Kindly help to convert pipe delimited text into excel with negative sign in front of the text.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `tr`. Please open the `filename_Final.csv` with a text editor and you will see `1,abc,-123`. `Excel` will change the position of the negative sign because your default number format of your locale region and language has set it so. See http://www.solveyourtech.com/change-the-windows-7-negative-number-format/.

Comment: @Abirami: Why can't you clarify your problem in a single post, you don't have to post the same question thrice http://stackoverflow.com/users/6891844/abirami?tab=questions

Answer (score 0):

Your `tr` call works as expected. Are you sure you have the `123-` in the resulting csv file? Isn't that just Excel representation of the negative value? Please inspect your csv file in a text editor.

I've tried your example:

```
# cat test
1|abc|-123 2|def|456 3|ijk|789
# cat test | tr '|' ','
1,abc,-123 2,def,456 3,ijk,789
```

Comment: Hi i tried to execute the above script and opened the file in notepad but still negative sign is in the back of the text. Please help.

Comment: Please let me know script to swap the negative sign from trailing end to leading end using tr command.

Answer (score 0):

Sample input:

```
cat csv
1|abc|-123
2|def|456
3|ijk|789
```

`awk` solution:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS="\t" '{$1=$1}1' csv
1       abc     -123
2       def     456
3       ijk     789
```

To make changes in `csv` : If your awk support inplace editing then use `-i` else:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS="\t" '{$1=$1}1' csv >csv.tmp && mv csv.tmp csv
```

Or old good `tr` :

```
tr '|' '\t' <csv
1       abc     -123
2       def     456
3       ijk     789
```

Answer (score 0):

*My requirement is to convert pipe separated file into normal excel*

You can just open the file in Excel, with the pipes, and then use the Data ► Text to columns wizard to split it into columns, and specify how to treat the trailing minus sign.

Or, you can use the Data ► Get External Data ► from Text option, which will also open the wizard.

Or you can use a VBA routine

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetUnixFile()
    Dim sFile

sFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt; *.csv), *.txt; *.csv")
If sFile = False Then Exit Sub

Workbooks.OpenText sFile, _
    startrow:=1, _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    textqualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, _
    consecutivedelimiter:=False, _
    Tab:=False, semicolon:=False, comma:=False, Space:=False, _
    other:=True, otherchar:="|", _
    trailingminusnumbers:=True


End Sub
```